# What is best possible way to handle Mysql db in Express.js app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I need to use Mysql in my express app. How should I implement it?

Comment: In a JS file, implement connection and pool part and when you want to query the DB, get a connection from that pool.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement it with a connection pool like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

const getConnection = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          resolve(connection);
        }
      });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getConnection,
};
```

And you can get a connection from this pool like this:

```
getConnection().then((conn) => {
   conn.query(<your query>, (error, results, fields) => {
         // do things here;
         conn.release();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this link https://medium.com/@avanthikameenakshi/building-restful-api-with-nodejs-and-mysql-in-10-min-ff740043d4be

install mysql using npm `npm install mysql --save`

in your app.js or index.js in your root directory connect to mysql:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : ' ',
        database : 'test'
    });
    res.locals.connect();
    next();
});
```

mysql connection is now added in `res` and you can now make a query by calling `res.locals.connection.query` in your custom endpoint